# I cannot retrieve a session variable in a second PHP file

Tags: php, session

What I am trying to do is, I have an HTML page that is an admin login form.  I want to pass the username to other pages to verify that the user is logged in before being allowed to access the functions of the called page.

I have this code in an PHP file that is included in an .html file:

```
session_start();
session_register('username');
$_SESSION['id']=10;
echo "Login session id is " .$_SESSION['id'];

unset($_SESSION['username']);
// Only process POST reqeusts.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
    require_once 'config.inc.php';

    $connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    else
    {
        $uName = $_POST['name'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $uName;
        echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

..... > more to the file but this displays the username just fine.

In the second file, a .html file with PHP inline in the file:

```
<?php

        session_start();

        echo "Add user session id is ";
        echo "<br>";
        echo $_SESSION['id'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Hello";
        echo "<br>";
        echo $_SESSION['username'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $_SESSION;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $_SESSION['time'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo date('Y m d H:i:s', $_SESSION['time']);
```

The hard code text and the "echo date('Y m d H:i:s', $_SESSION['time']);"   display fine.  The line echo date('Y m d H:i:s', $_SESSION['time']); displays the wort Array.

Can anyone tell me why I can't get the value of username?

Comment: remove spaces in second file before `session_start();` This will work

Comment: @Mubin I'm curious how the indenting of the file could cause it to fail?

Comment: Why are you still using `session_register`, that was deprecated ages ago.

Comment: I found the session_register while doing a google search for this issue.  It did not mention it was deprecated and I was just trying everything I saw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is as you said yourself,

> In the second file, a .html file with PHP inline in the file:

`PHP` has to be in a `.php` file, not a `.html` file extension.

**Edit 1:**

As per [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php):

*Warning
This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.*

You should stop using it.

**Edit 2:**

You are also echoing `$_SESSION`,

```
echo $_SESSION;
```

that should be throwing an `array to string conversion` error if your error reporting is enabled and the file extension is `.php`.

Comment: PHP does not have to be in a `.php` file.

Comment: @Don'tPanic It cannot be in a `.html` file. I know it can be in other file types such as `.phtml` but I was merely using it as an example as `.php` is probably the most widely used one for PHP files.

Comment: Why not? It can be in whatever kind of file you have configured your web server to handle with PHP. Including PHP code in `.html` files is common, and the file extension has no bearing on PHP's ability to interpret the file.

Comment: @Don'tPanic that is true yes, but quite often a default setup does not work like that. Looking at the OP's question and knowledge I highly doubt their server is setup like that. Yes, I am making assumptions but it is safe to make reasonable assumptions like this.

Comment: Non of these have worked for me.  Anyone have any examples of code to accomplish what I need?  I am creating administrative section on a website.  Once the user logs in I want to be able to validate that the user is logged in when they go to different pages.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest example i could come up with.  I hope it helps.

HTML

```
<form action="signin.php" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    Password: <input type="text" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP [signin.php]

```
<?php
    if($_POST['username'] == 'username') && $_POST['password'] == 'password')
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("location: admin.php");
    }
    else
    {
        header('location: error.php?msg=Invalid_Username';
    }
?>
```

PHP [error.php]

```
<?php
    $msg = '';
    if(isset($_GET['msg']))
    {
         if($_GET['msg'] == "Invalid_Username")
         {
            $msg = "Your username or password didn't match.";
        }
        else if($_GET['msg'] == "Invalid_Access")
        {
            $msg = 'You are not allowed on that page.';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = 'Unknown Error';
    }
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>ERROR</h1>
        <p><?php echo $msg;?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP [admin.php]

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['username'])
    {
       echo 'your signed in';
    }
    else
    {
        header('location: error.php?msg=Invalid_Access');
    }
?>
```